# Is there anyway I can put a variable inside a value tag in HTML?

Tags: html, tags

I would like to have a

```
      <input type="text" value=VARIABLENAME />.
```

Is there anyway I can do this? Putting value = "VARIABLENAME" interprets it as the name of the variable. But I would like to assign the content of the variable to the value property.

EDIT: The variable is from the text content of one of my tables. I got the variable by using doing something like this in my script tag.

```
       selectedScheduleName = e.target.childNodes[0].wholeText;
```

Thank you.

Comment: There is no such thing as a variable in HTML terms, so this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Where is this variable coming from?

Comment: I have a javascript variable that I would like to put in the value property. Is that more clear?

Comment: You need to use javascript. HTML is a markup language.

Comment: Richard, is there a method in javascript that could change the attribute of the input tag? would using the setAttribute() method work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can *assign* a value to the input's [`value` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-value) from a variable, e.g.:

```
theInput.value = theVariable;
```

You do this in the JavaScript, after getting a reference to the `input` element.

So for instance, if you give the `input` an `id` value of "foo", you can do this:

```
document.getElementById("foo").value = theVariable;
```

...within a `script` tag. (Be sure that the `input` has already been added to the DOM first, either by putting the script after it — the bottom of the `body` tag is good — or by using `window`'s `load` event or, if you use a library that supports one, some kind of "dom ready" event.)

The element doesn't have to have an `id`, if you can get at it via `getElementsByTagName` or by the `form` element's `elements` array, etc., etc.

Handy references:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) specification (well supported cross-browser)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) specification (reasonably well supported cross-browser)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) specification (not quite as well supported cross-browser yet)
- The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) now has IDL for the HTML DOM objects in it directly (supplanting/supplementing the DOM2 HTML spec), such as for [`HTMLElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#htmlelement), [`HTMLFormElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmlformelement), and [`HTMLInputElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-input-element.html#htmlinputelement)

Comment: Thank you TJ, that is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry to everyone about being unclear originally.

Answer (score -1):

If as you say you have a JavaScript variable you wish to apply:

```
var foo = "Testing";
document.GetElementById('ElementID').value = foo;
```

or using jQuery:

```
var foo = "Testing";
$("#ElementID").val(foo);
```